# Parse files with Java - Select appropriate functions/classes

Tags: java, reflection

Assuming I have a file with the following text:

```
sum 5 3
print hello
split testing t
...
```

I have a package with all the "classes": module_sum, module_print, module_split - and many more.
I want to be able to read the first word (which is the class), and then to intiailize the class with the rest of the sentence as a parameter (of String type) or to output an error if the function doesn't exists.

What is the best way to do it? I might have hundreds of "modules_X" files.

Thanks!

Comment: You've called a class `module_sum`?

Comment: I don't think Reflection will be a good fit for this..

Comment: this is screaming for a re-design

Comment: Nim, which other options do you suggest? assuming I want to have the ability to easilly add new "functionalities"?

Comment: @Avenger - I would not mess with Reflection on such a large scale. In the end even you will not be knowing the flow of your program..

Comment: @TheLostMind - So my only feasible option would be to use a large switch-case, or pre-make a list of all the classes?

Comment: I can't say that for sure  Not until you give the a clearer picture of what you want to achieve..

Comment: exactly that - to be able to parse a command file and execute functions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

what about something like

```
String[] input = reader.readLine().split(' ');
switch(input[0])
{
    case "sum": //call sum
    case "print": // call print
    //etc.
    default: throw new Exception(); //whichever you like
}
```

Comment: Problem is I'll have to change the switch-case each time I add a new functionality.